# Security of email (SMTP/POP) passwords

Tags: authentication

In my client mail app (ThunderBird) I chose (and my mail server accepted) SMTP with STARTTLS, the POP (or POP3) with SSL/TLS. I understand that this is for mail content from my client app to my ISP mail server only.

My question is specifically for the security of this connection to the mail server -  i.e. ThunderBird's connection Security drop-down options are,
No Authentication, Normal Password, Encrypted Password, Kerberos / GSSAPI, NTLM, and OAuth2.  ThunderBird can also probe my Email Server for what it is able to comply or implement on its end. Which I found for my server was only "Normal Password".

So apparently my email server does not offer an encrypted connection and I surmise my password can be seen by someone with sufficient skills. Additionally, I'm curious if there are any email servers (ISP provided or other) that offer Password Encryption.

Answer (score 5):

There are two separate aspects of the configuration here - the connection-level security, and the authentication-level security.  In practice, since connection-level (TLS) protects both, it is common for authentication-level security to be low ("Normal Password").  **As long as you're using TLS (SMTP/POP/IMAP either over SSL/TLS or STARTTLS), you're fine.**

### Why?

Way back, before SSL/TLS/STARTTLS became common, the credentials were the only part of the connection people cared about protecting.  As you say, email may be transmitted unencrypted as soon as it leaves your server - so people were not deeply concerned about the potential for that being read.  However, they were concerned about their credentials.  And those credentials used to pass over an unencrypted SMTP/POP/IMAP link.

For that reason, a number of protocols specially designed to encrypt the credentials were devised.  Digest-MD5, GSSAPI, and OAUTH were all more secure [SMTP AUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication) methods which could be used over an unencrypted connection.  The more common types PLAIN and LOGIN, which do not encrypt credentials, would leave the password vulnerable *if there were no connection-level encryption*.

But then the world started encrypting the connection.  SMTP, POP and IMAP clients and servers added support for SSL/TLS or STARTTLS to protect the entire connection.  Once they became common, there was little motivation to use the more complex protected SMTP AUTH methods, because the TLS would provide all the necessary protection.  That's why your ISP is comfortable only offering "Normal Password" (which is PLAIN and/or LOGIN) - they know the TLS layer protects you.

(In fact, some stronger methods weaken security, by requiring that the server store a plaintext or reversibly encrypted copy of each user's password, rather than a one-way hash of it.  To quote [Wikipedia on Digest Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)), "*Some servers require passwords to be stored using reversible encryption. However, it is possible to instead store the digested value of the username, realm, and password.*"  The footnote link for that latter statement goes to [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-4.13) which goes into more detail about the security trade-offs of Digest Authentication...  I've considered implementing Digest Authentication with Postfix, Dovecot, Courier, and Cyrus over the years; each time I decided I didn't like the trade-off.)

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on your last scentence about stronger methods weakening security due to storing plaintext?

Comment: @Daisetsu done... it's been long enough I don't recall which particular implementations I looked at over the years, but they did require plaintext passwords.

Comment: "As long as you're using TLS ... you're fine" - unfortunately, with STARTTLS, you don't know if you are using TLS: "A man-in-the-middle attack can be launched by deleting the "250 STARTTLS" response from the server" - rfc 2307

Comment: @symcbean: Well, that's arguably a bug in the client implementation. The client _does_ know that STARTTLS failed, and can then abandon the connection. All decent SMTP clients I know (e.g. Exim and Thunderbird) have an option for that, usually called "require TLS" or similar.

Comment: Implementing the protocol as described in the RFC is a bug?